# Change "No Internet" screen on PyQt6 Browser

Tags: pyqt6

[Is there a way to change this screen and the others in PyQt6 browser?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1eMf.png)

Comment: That is a page built into Chromium, so probably not

Comment: better you write in white paper what message you want  and paste in monitor.

Comment: @AravindAravind can you explain how to? It's okay if you can't.